# Ksplice - What happen if server power-down when updating kernel

Tags: kernel

I am finding a rebootless solution for updating kernel.
I saw Ksplice.
I have a question:
**What happen if our servers power-off when updating use Ksplice? Our servers will be OK? What will revert our servers?**
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the Ksplice User's Guide (http://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/guide):

> Ksplice and Kernel VersionsBack to top Ksplice Uptrack updates your
>   running kernel in memory. We recommended that, in addition to using
>   Ksplice, you continue to use your package manager to update the kernel
>   on disk as new kernels become available. That way, if a reboot becomes
>   necessary (e.g. power loss or a hardware upgrade) you have the option
>   of booting into a newer kernel. Under this plan, you would install all
>   the updates available via both Ksplice Uptrack and your package
>   manager.
>
> Ksplice Uptrack also works great in environments where it is desirable
>   to stay with a particular original kernel version (e.g. because of
>   third party modules that are compiled against that kernel) but you
>   want to stay up to date with all the important security and
>   reliability updates for your kernel.
>
> By default, Ksplice Uptrack will reinstall rebootless updates during
>   the boot process so you remain secure even after a reboot. You can
>   configure this behavior by changing the `install_on_reboot` option in
>   `/etc/uptrack/uptrack.conf`.
>
> [...]
>
> `install_on_reboot` will restore the Linux kernel to the same version
>   as before rebooting. There may be additional updates that could be
>   applied. If you wish all available updates for a particular kernel
>   version to be applied, set `upgrade_on_reboot` to `yes`.

So, nothing bad should occur. If a power loss happens, your system will boot on the default kernel version and Ksplice will by default re patch your system with security updates at boot time so you don't get uncovered. It will make your boot time longer, so, if you need a faster boot, you should install the updates for your packages using your default package manager too.

As a note, if you will update the kernel of a server you should like to do a kernel only update, isolated from other system updates, always as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Your information is very helpful with me :)
I have more questions:
- While kernel updating, power loss -> new kernel updated failed, how my server know that?
-> when power on, will there nothing install?
I set install_on_reboot option in /etc/uptrack/uptrack.conf = yes

Comment: @duka Ksplice will keep track of some information about your system, that you can access using the uptrack tool. Basically Ksplice knows what updates was already installed and what not. This implies that, if the installation was not successful and you have install_on_reboot set to false, you will see a discrepancy between the exit of uptrack-show and uptrack-show ----available. This makes Ksplice able to know that something has going wrong, load the kernel from disk and apply what is missing automatically if install_on_reboot is set to yes.

Comment: Thanks :)
"Ksplice Uptrack will reinstall rebootless updates during the boot process so you remain secure even after a reboot."
---
BUT, if power loss again when "reinstall rebootless updates" above...
- Some updates were installed
- But some updates were not installed. Am I right? How does Ksplice install them?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @duka Ksplice will verify the integrity of your kernel, see what updates was successfuly applied and then install what is missing. Ksplice is a pretty strong system...